# I am a flutter beginner while getting json data from internet it is not showing in my app.. Solve it

Tags: json, flutter, dart

**This is my complete code and i don't know what kind of error i have made**

**Correct it if you know, as i am beginner in flutter.**

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: Mydata(),
    );
  }
}

class Mydata extends StatefulWidget {
  const Mydata({super.key});
  @override
  State<Mydata> createState() => _MydataState();
}

class _MydataState extends State<Mydata> {
  Future<List<String>> ebdetails() async {
    var response =
        await http.get(Uri.parse('http://117.247.181.113:8000/eb/1/'));
    return jsonDecode(response.body);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: const Text(
          'Json Datas',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return const Center(
                child: Text('Data Error'),
              );
            } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Center(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                  return Text(
                    snapshot.data![i],
                  );
                },
              ));
            } else {
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            }
          },
          future: ebdetails(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

*I am fetching data over local ip but it seems to have some sort of error i have made, but its hard for me to find..* 
*It shows only "Data error* which i have given in Futurebuilder..

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "R_Current": -1.0,
        "Y_Current": -1.0,
        "B_Current": -1.0,
        "R_Voltage": 208,
        "Y_Voltage": 235,
        "B_Voltage": 208,
        "UPS_Voltage": 100,
        "UPS_Current": 143.0,
        "UPS_Battery": 99
    }
]
```

Comment: place print() statement at different places to find out the place which is causing the issue

Comment: and i think this is causing the issue return jsonDecode(response.body); you have the declared  the return type to be list and check if it is list or not

Comment: i have added the data

Answer (score 1):

so according to your data it is not the list of the String change the return type of the method to this

```
Future<List<dynamic>> ebdetails() async {
var response =
    await http.get(Uri.parse('http://117.247.181.113:8000/eb/1/'));
return jsonDecode(response.body);
}
```

Edit:
Ok so your problem was that you pass map to the Text() widget and the text widget needs string as a parameter so you have to convert the snapshot.data to string and then pass it to the Text widget.

```
snapshot.data.toString()
```

Comment: changed it but it still showing has.error in Futurebuilder

Comment: change to this Future<List>  ebdetails()

Comment: no it doesn't work, is there anything i need to change with snapshot.data or something

Comment: create a button and call the ebdetails with the button on pressed and print the returned result to find out if the error is in the future method or the future builder

Comment: its showing error in asynchronomous suspension and <!Doctype html>

Comment: so the error is in the http.get check the you are not receiving correct data from the request

Comment: http.get is correct but the actual error is i have change snapshot.data to snapshot.data.toString(), anyways thank you for your support..

Comment: check the answer i updated it and your problem was this accept it if your problem is solved

Answer (score 1):

try to convert the response into a custom Dart object

see this
[1]: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data

Answer (score 0):

**I have changed the code and got the answer i.e snapshot.data![i].toString()**

```
builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Center(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                  return Text(
                    snapshot.data![i].toString(),
                  );
```